# Problems accessing a Model function in View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class, Teacher, that has multiple integer columns:

```
t.integer :a_students
t.integer :b_students
t.integer :c_students
t.integer :d_students
t.integer :f_students
```

And I have a view that loops through all the teachers and states how many students are in their class.  Now although I could add all the students in the view, just to make it look nicer I want to offload adding all the students into the model.  I have the following model method:

```
  def count_students( teacher_id )
    t = Teacher.find(teacher_id)
    total = t.a_students + t.b_students + t.c_students + t.d_students + t.f_students
    total
  end
```

If I'm not mistaken, I shouldn't be accessing model methods from the view - that should be left to the controller.  But since its looping through, I'm a little lost on what to do in this case.  Any Ideas?

Thanks
Ben

Comment: There's nothing wrong with calling model methods from a view so long as there isn't any view code (e.g. html) in those methods.

Comment: @jeffpeterson it may be doable, but it would be better to separate your concerns.

Comment: @jeffpeterson well that's good to know, I've been working under the assumption its completely taboo!

Comment: @cadlac To be clear, I'm referring to instance methods (`@teacher.count_students`) and not class methods (`Teacher.count_students(@teacher.id)`). Model class methods typically shouldn't be in your views.

Comment: @jeffpeterson well that helps as well!  Explains why I had the idea in my head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your teacher model have a method something like this:

```
def total_students
  a_students + b_students + c_students + d_students + e_students + f_students
end
```

Then in your view if you have t, a particular teacher, you can just do t.total_students to get the total you want.

Comment: So much simpler than I though! Thanks @Edward

Answer (score 2):

That method in the Teacher model class would be an instance method. So you do not need to do a call to the DB to find the teacher since you already have that information:

```
def count_students
    total = a_students + b_students + c_students + d_students + f_students
end
```

You can also access instance variables and methods using `self`. Ruby also returns the value last calculated, so you don't need the last total.

Answer (score 1):

Why not move your code to your controller and why do you have all these different students?

If you want to collect all the students from a particular teacher, this will do:

```
@teacher = Teacher.find(params[:teacher_id])
@students = @teacher.students.all
```

But hey, maybe I just misunderstand your question.

Comment: This would assume there is an association already setup for teachers and students (as well as student records). It would be better to have this if cadlac were using that approach, but it won't work in this case.

Comment: True, but I'm wondering why he would not use this approach. It seems a lot cleaner to me. Better yet, his app can stay completely REST.

Comment: @PeterdeRidder the reason I'm not using associations is because this isn't a real app.  In a real app I definitely would, you're right, but I am just messing around and seeing what problems I run into :D

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you should be conducting any mid-way logic. What is the purpose of this looping through? Does it return the value total? And if it does, why can't you conduct this in the controller and return the result of the operation to the view?

Comment: The controller shouldn't have to worry about the logic for the total # of students for a teacher.